# Convert this function using trig identities into sine functions

Tags: trigonometry

$f(x) = 8 \cos^4 x + 6 \sin (2x + 3 \pi/4) \sin(2x - \pi/4)$.

How can I simplify into a linear combination of simple sine functions?

Comment: `FullSimplify[8 Cos[x]^4 + 6 Sin[2 x + 3 Pi/4] Sin[2 x - Pi/4]]` returns a simple expression (`4 Cos[2 x] + Cos[4 x] + 3 Sin[4 x]`), but it's a combination of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Would that work?

Comment: how did you get it to 3sin(4x)?

Comment: Is this a question about the computing software *Mathematica* or is it just a [math.se] question?

Comment: Or `TrigReduce[]`.

Comment: The problem seems to be that _Mathematica_ automatically simplifies `Sin[y + Pi/2]` to `Cos[y]`, as you can see with `Hold[Sin[y + Pi/2]]` `ReleaseHold[%]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this?:

```
FourierTrigSeries[8 Cos[x]^4 + 6 Sin[2 x + 3 Pi/4] Sin[2 x - Pi/4], x, 4] /.
 Cos[t_] :> HoldForm[Sin][Pi/2 - t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm assuming it's primarily about formatting the output in terms of sines.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that if we take the Fourier transform of it to get the discrete frequencies and then invert the transform, that the expression would be simpler. It comes back in exponential form, and the leading coefficient needs to be distributed. From there, you can use Euler's equation to transform it back to trig. The remaining required transforms are trivial. I have no idea if this is how you were supposed to solve it.

```
FourierTransform[8 Cos[x]^4 + 6Sin[2x + 3Pi/4]Sin[2x - Pi/4],x,w];
InverseFourierTransform[%,w,t];
Distribute@%;
ExpToTrig@%
(*4 Cos[2 t]+Cos[4 t]+3 Sin[4 t]*)
```

Comment: is it possible to change 4 cos (2t) + cos (4t) into sine function? ie : A1Sin(2pix + theta) + A2sin(2pix + theta) + ..

Comment: @SandWu:  Can't you simply add $\pi/2$ to the arguments of Cosines to get sines?

Answer (score -2):

$4 \cos (2 t) + \cos (4 t) + 3 \sin (4 t) = 4 \sin (2 t + \pi/2) + \sin (4 t + \pi/2) + 3 \sin (4 t)$